# Force C# compiler error based on const value

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I have a private const int defined in a C# class. I want compilation to fail with an error if the value of this int mod 3 != 0. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I'm disappointed that there's no "real" way to do this with the "preprocessor" directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timothy Khouri almost got it. It should be this:

```
int compilerError = 1 / (MY_CONST % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Even better. Very neat solution

Comment: Yep, this is what I wanted.

Strikes me as odd that one user can edit another user's answer and not leave a trace of what he originally wrote. David, are you some kind of moderator or something?

Comment: No I just have enough rep to edit posts. I'm a rep newbie compared with the mighty maxidad though :)

Comment: Sorry, but just reading the answer it is incomprehensible. What does this one-liner mean?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is an [*#error*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0.aspx) pre-processor directive for generating compile-time errors, there is no way for it to be based on the existence of a const value. It only works with compiler symbols, like "DEBUG", for which a value can't be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that code I said below won't work, but this will :)

```
int pointless = 1 / (MY_CONST % 3);
```

The reason why this will work is because you'll get a compile time, "can't devide by zero" error. Your "MY_CONST" field will have to be anything that (once modded by 3) will not be equal to zero.

Comment: That will cause a runtime failure, not a compile-time failure.

Comment: it does raise an error if const % 3 == 0, but the question asker asked for when const % 3 != 0

Comment: Not sure if I've read the question wrong, but you are causing an error if int MOD 3 == 0, whereas I think the question was for int MOD 3 != 0. So you'd need three lines to cover MY_CONST % 3 == 1, == 2 & == 3

Comment: Sorry, ignore the MY_CONST % 3 == 3 option as that's impossible. Doh!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (MY_CONST % 3 != 0) { int compilerError = 1 / 0; }
```

Comment: Please unmark this post as the answer, and use the one that I said below (the (MY_CONST % 3) one).